# JS google api translate srt file

Tags: javascript, api, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-translate

I have a file of `3674 lines`, the file is the one in the link below is a srt file, for video subtitles.

Link: [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/K9McqwEm)

I looked in the documentation but I am not able to find the right `API` that allows me to upload a file, for example `txt` as you can do through google translate, upload the file and then translate it into the desired language.

Link: [translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=it&op=docs)

I found in bees only the possibility of passing small texts in the url, and then they are translated.

But being texts with many lines, it is not possible to do this because there is a limit on the part of the bees of how many translation requests can be made in a certain period of time.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Having quickly looked through google api for translation, I found [this request](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations/batchTranslateText) for translating large texts in it.